# Param Tuning with Keras and Hyperas

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have been working with a Python library called Hyperas which is a hyperopt/keras wrapper for tuning parameters in a Keras model. My question is about the output from Hyperas.

I have read the documentation and source code, but cannot seem to figure out what the output means or how to interpret. It prints the following line after it is done optimizing:

```
{'batch_size': 3, 'optimizer': 1, 'l2': 0.7446290506725413, 'output_dim': 3, 'output_dim_1': 0, 'l2_1': 0.12090219120950985}
```

Why are there two dictionary values for output_dim, even though there is only one output_dim param in my code? How do I interpret everything elese?

```
def model(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, max_features, maxlen, class_weight_dict):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Embedding(max_features, output_dim = {{choice([32,64,128,256,512])}}, input_length=maxlen))
        model.add(LSTM({{choice([32,64,128,256,512])}},W_regularizer=l2({{uniform(0, 1)}})))
        model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 1)}}))
        model.add(Dense(138))
        model.add(Activation('softmax'))

        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer={{choice(['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd'])}},
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4)
        checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='keras_weights.hdf5',
                                       verbose=1,
                                       save_best_only=True)

        model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                  batch_size={{choice([32,16,64,128,256,512])}},
                  validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                  nb_epoch=100,
                  class_weight=class_weight_dict,
                  callbacks=[early_stopping, checkpointer])

        score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
        print('Test score:', score)
        print('Test accuracy:', acc)
        return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model,
                                              data=data,
                                              algo=tpe.suggest,
                                              max_evals=10,
                                              trials=Trials())
        print(best_run)
        print(best_model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's because you have your parameters not named, let's have a look at this line:

```
 model.add(LSTM({{choice([32,64,128,256,512])}},W_regularizer=l2({{uniform(0, 1)}})))
```

as this `choice` is unnamed - `hyperas` is scanning function definition and is looking for the parameter name. As it's not named - it assigns the value of the previously named parameter which is `output_1`. In order to skip that try:

```
model.add(LSTM(units={{choice([32,64,128,256,512])}},...)
```

And do a similar thing with dropout rate:

```
model.add(Dropout(rate=..))
```

Comment: Awesome. So for the output, ({'batch_size': 3, 'optimizer': 1}) for example, do the numbers indicate the index of the best params for each? Ie. for batch size i would use the size that was in the 3rd position?

Comment: Right :) The value is an index of the best parameter.

Comment: I have found `hyperas` to fail to label some parameters. For example, I get `{'dropout': 0.19540010347590975, 'dropout_1': 0.1673333369423164}` from `x = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True,dropout={{uniform(0, 0.2)}}, recurrent_dropout={{uniform(0, 0.2)}}))(x)`